# Xcode 4.6.1 on Mac is very slow. It uses 500% CPU and 5G ram

Tags: xcode, performance, macos

My xcode uses 5G ram on my computer (mac os 10.7.5).  My mac has 2.7 GHz Interl Core i7 processor, I have 8G memory.

If I open my xcode, I can not do anything.  What is wrong with this xcode?  anyone can help.

I restarted my computer, I reinstalled the latest xcode, none of these helped.  I can not do anything with xcode.

Anyone has any suggestion how to fix the issue.  Thanks

Comment: 500%. Is that all? That still leaves 3 cores totally ununtilised :-)

Comment: Do you have this usage on every project (I doubt that) or on a specific one ? Check headers imports, project headers search path maybe. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225603/xcode-4-became-extremely-slow-and-kills-my-hard-drive?rq=1

Comment: Have you tried resetting Xcode with `defaults delete com.apple.Xcode; rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Xcode`? Make sure to back up the settings first.

Comment: No kidding.  I am very frustrated about the stupid xcode.

Comment: How do I back up settings? I never did that.

Comment: For what it's worth, the current Xcode is 4.6.1.

Comment: JWWalker.  Yes, It is Xcode 4.6.1

Comment: Has Xcode finished indexing your project? I know that the first time I open a project after doing a checkout or clone from a source repository, it takes Xcode *forever* to index it, and that uses up both disk and CPU. But once it finishes, everything's back to normal. Also, are you compiling a lot of C++? Or mainly Objective-C? It seems to get really bogged down when compiling template-heavy C++, I've noticed.

Comment: I don't know why my xcode does indexing all the time, every few mintues, it is indexing my project.  I don't think my project is too big.  but it is not small either.

Comment: If you have a Developer account of any kind with Apple, open a support ticket.

Answer (score 3):

If your xcode is consuming that much of RAM and CPU, then surely it is doing few things in background.

Indexing your project. And your project is most likely to be a big one.

Downloading Components and Documentations. Try UnCheck these.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I met the same case, and found out that **the "comparing" view would cause the problem**(both when committing to SVN and switching to "Show the version Editor" in the Main window)

But until now I don't find any solution after trying to upgrade to 4.6.2, restart and open other projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

- Find your project file.
- Right-click on it, then select **Show Package Contents**.
- Next, delete `project.xcworkspace`.